# How to pass an array as parameter from Hibernate to PL/SQL?

Tags: arrays, hibernate, plsql

I need to pass an array of integers from Hibernate to PL/SQL function. The current solution is the covert the array to a comma separated string and surround it with parenthesis to use it as parameter. This is solution is outlined [here](http://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2323190&sid=f50814e84d17f277eb74cc6755163e1c).

But, this approach doesn't look like a good solution when an array of 200k elements need to be passed around.

Is there any way to pass this array using Hibernate's constructs?

Edit: I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3):

It would not be advisable to pass a 200k element array to a database function. I would think a better approach would be to insert these values as a bulk insert into a separate table, then call the function and have it reference the table.